# Switching over an email address from a distribution group to a user account in Exchange 2003

Tags: email, exchange-2003, mailbox

I'm currently in a transition mode.  We currently have a Distribution Group called Quotes and Orders that send out emails to several users.  I'm told that a better method would be to create a user and then give access to that fictitious user's email account so that everyone would be able to see everything that goes out and is responded to in a single account.

However, I'm not sure what the best method would be for creating an account and shutting down the distribution group. I'm thinking more along the lines of the steps that considered best practice to remove the email account from the distribution group and attach it to the user account.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Users need to know what will happen, when, and how they will access the mailboxes in the future.

The process of removing the old list and establishing the new full accounts with mailboxes should leave very little gap where the address does not exist.

1) Create the new full AD accounts and Exchange mailboxes.  Name the account slightly different than the current distribution list so there isn't overlap in the email addresses.

2) Assign either the proper delegate rights or mailbox permissions so the users have access(use Groups!).

3) Setup/instruct the individual users to access the new full accounts

4) Remove the distribution list

5) Go back to the AD account and add an additional SMTP email address that matches the distribution list email address.

Good Luck!

Comment: 6) Set that new SMTP address to be the Reply To/Primary address.